# cannot access the wordpress dashboard after changing the site url

Tags: admin

I have changed the site url in bluhost, from then unable to open the site and page promts me sever IP address could not be found err-name-not resolved.

i have checked php admin database both the site url and the home are same. please help me with this

thanks in advance

Comment: What did you change the URL to? Do you own that domain, and have you pointed it to your website?

Comment: I have changed the temporary domain url

Comment: Is the new URL or Domain on the same IP address as the old one? If you ping your domain name does the IP address match the IP for the new URL.